# Error message: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, wshttpbinding, channelfactory

I am trying to access a WCF service (MS CRM 2011) and getting the above error.  If I run my sample program from the VS2010 debugger with either Cassini or IIS Express it works great.  No authentication errors.

However, if I publish the site to my local IIS 7.5 (running Windows 7 64 bit), I get the error on the line that grabs the CRM UserId (WhoAmIResponse).

I opened Fiddler to compare the requests between running under the debugger and running under IIS.  On the site running under IIS the request never even comes across, so it must be failing before getting that far.

The site as published to IIS has its web.config set for ...

```
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

The site is running under the preinstalled ASP.NET v4.0 app pool, Integrated pipeline mode, ApplicationPoolIdentity account.

Here is my code...

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        var _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("http://svr-rex2011-dev/TimeEntry/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"),
                                                            null,
                                                            credentials,
                                                            null);

        // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
        _serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

        IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;

        // Display information about the logged on user.
        Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
        SystemUser systemUser = (SystemUser)service.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
            new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" }));

        // Retrieve the version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
        RetrieveVersionRequest versionRequest = new RetrieveVersionRequest();
        RetrieveVersionResponse versionResponse =
            (RetrieveVersionResponse)service.Execute(versionRequest);

        ViewBag.FirstName = systemUser.FirstName;
        ViewBag.LastName = systemUser.LastName;
        ViewBag.Version = versionResponse.Version;

        return View();
    }

}
```

Any ideas?  Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the situation you are describing is this: you are getting authentication errors when your app tries to access the CRM service when it is running on IIS. When you run your app from Visual Studio or IIS Express then you don't have authentication errors.

If this is true, I'm pretty sure your issue is due to the identity used to run the IIS AppPool for your application. You need to [change the AppPool identity](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) to one that has network access to the CRM service. Normally it should be a domain account with the correct permissions but there are ways of doing this using local machine accounts that have the same password (definitely not recommend if a domain is available).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I changed the account to run as NetworkService and experienced the same results.  So are you suggesting not using the 'Built-in account' option in favor of the 'Custom account' option?  I tried that as well with a domain account that has Administrator access into the box that hosts the WCF service.  Same issue.

Comment: Right, the Network Service identity is the same thing as the domain assigned machine account for that server (usually the server name). Most likely that account isn't in a domain group that has access to the CRM service. To verify that this is the issue, temporarily assign the AppPool your domain account and recycle IIS. Try your application again and if it calls successfully, you'll know its an account authentication issue. The long term fix is to request a domain account in a group that has access to assign to the AppPool.

Comment: I didn't notice the bit about the Administrator account. Depending on what rights the admin account was given, it may or may not have access to the CRM service. I would try with your account since you know it does have access to CRM service.

Comment: Ok, I am getting closer.  I set the app pool account to a domain account that has Adminstrator access on the box that hosts the WCF service (which I had done previously).  However this time I opened the Authentication area under the website.  There are four options, three were enabled including ASP.NET Impersonation.  I disabled that option and now the service gets called.  However, the user that is passed to the service is the account in the app pool!  I need instead to pass the creds of the user that is logged into the computer.  Any other thoughts on how to make that happen?

Comment: I have my authentication mode set to Windows, and I am trying to set the credentials by using the CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, but I need the DefaultNetworkCredentials to not get the creds from the app pool but rather the logged in user.

Comment: I think I need ASP.NET impersonation.  It seems if I can get this to work, then I will be down the road.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is a identity delegation. Here is an [article that explains how that scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517269.aspx) is configured. If your ActiveDirectory set up doesn't have Federation Services enabled you won't be able to do what you want. I believe by default, ActiveDirectory only permits one impersonation "hop". Basically, unless you set up identity delegation you cannot impersonate an identity twice.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and, in my case, it turned out to be due to the fact that CRM was load-balanced.  It turns out that [Authentication delegation through Kerberos does not work in load-balanced architectures](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325608).

We got around this by pointing our application directly to one of the CRM servers via a HOST entry, which bypassed the load balancing.

I hope that saves someone the several hours it cost me.