# WCF - "The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed"

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, visual-studio, web-services

I've created a WCF service and hosted it in IIS7/Windows Server 2008.
I'm trying to consume the service in my application...
When I run the application from Visual Studio (debug), I can call the service and everything works as expected, however, when I attempt to call the service from the published application, I get the error above.

Here's the service's web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    ...
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" />
    </system.web>

    <runtime>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>    
    <system.serviceModel>               
        <services>            
            <service name="SVCLIB.SERVICE1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SVCLIB.SERVICE1">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/SVCLIB/SERVICE1/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>        
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And on the client:

```
  SERVICE1.SERVICE1Client objService = new SERVICE1Client();

  objService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "UserName";
  objService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";

  objService.GetData();
  objService.Close();
```

It works when debugging the application in VS, but it doesn't work when running the published application.

Error:

> The request for security token could not be satisfied because
>   authentication failed

I've looked at many posts here on Stack Overflow and others, but none helped me so far.

Thank you!

** EDIT:

This is on the web.config, in the client side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_SERVICE1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://server.samedomain.com:8000/SVCLIB.SERVICE1.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_SERVICE1"
        contract="SERVICE1.ISERVICE1" name="WSHttpBinding_ISERVICE1">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Tried gmail user's suggestion and link below... but still have the same problem. Same error.

Comment: Are you utilizing a config file on the client side or are you doing more in code configuration than you are showing here?  Are you sure the published client's app.config is the same one you are using in the debug?

Comment: @iMortalitySX: Yes. I'm using a config file on the client side (see edit above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what the problem is.
But for now I switched to [basicHttpBinding with Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try commenting the following lines in the published environment

```
<identity>
     <dns value="localhost" />
</identity>
<host>
    <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/SVCLIB/SERVICE1/" />
    </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Comment: Also I don't see any security settings in web.config. What is the security settings?

Comment: May be this is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981167/error-message-the-request-for-security-token-could-not-be-satisfied-because-aut

Comment: What is your security setting in web.config?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I still don't know what the problem is... but for now I switched to [basicHttpBinding with Windows Authentication](http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx). Thanks.